# Proving that $\lambda$ being an eigenvalue for $A$ implies $\lambda^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue for $A^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

Let $A$ be an invertible matrix, and let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue for $A$. We have that $Ax = \lambda x$ for some eigenvector $x$. Note that $A^{-1}Ax = A^{-1}\lambda x$, which gives $x = A^{-1}\lambda x$. Also note that multiplication with scalar is commutative, so this gives $\lambda^{-1}x = A^{-1}x$, which is the desired result.

That last sentence was a realization I made while I was writing the question; so the question has now changed to proof-verification.

Comment: Well apart from the part "...and implies $A^{-1}\lambda$ is the identity matrix.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $x=A^{-1}\lambda x$ does not necessarily mean that $A^{-1}\lambda$ is the identity matrix; what if, for instance, $x$ is the zero-vector?

But, you do have the right idea up until there with your second comment: that $A^{-1}\lambda=\lambda A^{-1}$, so that $\lambda^{-1}x=\lambda^{-1}\lambda A^{-1}x=A^{-1}x$.

Comment: Yes, I should've written the whole task, seeing as we were told to assume that $x$ is not the zero-vector. My mistake.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The fact that $x$ is not the zero-vector is not the point -- that's just one way that statement can go wrong. In general, $Bx=x$ for some vector $x$ just tells us that $x$ is in the $1$-eigenspace of the matrix $B$, not that $B$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The zero-vector is just easy to pick on, because it is trivially true that $B\vec{0}=\lambda\vec{0}$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is very confuzingly written.

What do you mean when you say $A^{-1}\lambda$ is the identity matrix? $A^{-1}$ is not necesarily diagonal, and $\lambda$ is a scalar, so the matrix is not always the identity...

It is much simpler, since you have $x=A^{-1}\lambda x$ means $x=\lambda A^{-1} x$. Now just multiply this equation with $\lambda^{-1}$ and you are done. On a side note, if I was grading an assignment like this, I would like my students to explain why $\lambda^{-1}$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is not [defective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_matrix), you can use the [eigendecomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition#Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix) $A=Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$ and therefore $A^{-1}=Q^{-1}\Lambda^{-1}Q$, where $\Lambda$ contains your eigenvaules and $\Lambda^{-1}$ their reciprocals...

Comment: I had never heard about the terminology defective, I'd +1 you for that if this answered the general case.

Comment: @GitGud 
The defective matrix $\pmatrix{1& 1 \\  0 & 1}$ is invertible, but doesn't have an eigendecomposition...

Comment: Agreed. Why are you telling me this?

Comment: @GitGud I thought an example would clarify that the way via the eigendecompositions only works for non-defective matrices...